java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of - after upgrade build tools to 8.4.0 version
I work with an internal sdk that I developed, and I communicate between the application and the sdk through an interface defined as keep.
So far everything has worked well as it should.
And from the moment I upgraded to 8.4
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.4.0'

While running, the compiler does not recognize the interface for me and throws an error like this:
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
ControllerInterface$DefaultImpls;

Anyone have an idea why? And how can it be solved?
this is my interface :
@Keep
object Controller : ControllerInterface {

    override fun connect(callback:ControllerCallback?) {
        InternalController.setRobotControllerCallback(callback)
    }
}

and this is the code from app:
 Controller.connect(
                object : ConnectionCallback {
                    override fun connectionComplete(
                        isConnect: Boolean,
                        status: Map<String, String>?,
                        Dict: Map<String, Any?>?
                    ) {
                        
                })

